# SQL Server: Change current database via variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and am trying to change the current database name to one in a variable. I normally do this explicitly with the statment `USE myDatabaseName`.
The question arises because if I am running a script and if I don't change the database name it creates all the tables in the `[master]` database.

I tried the following but doesn't seem to work as it keeps applying the rest of the `create tables` codes to `[master]`.

```
DECLARE @dbName CHAR(50)
DECLARE @SqlQuery varchar(50)
SET @dbName = 'MyNewDatabaseName'

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @dbName)
BEGIN
    SELECT @SqlQuery = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + @dbName + 'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
    EXEC(@SqlQuery) 
END

Select @SqlQuery = 'Use ' + @dbName
EXEC(@SqlQuery)
go
```

Comment: how are you running the script?

Comment: As a `new query` at the server level.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Executing `USE some_db` in dynamic SQL does work but unfortunately when the scope exits the database context gets changed back to what it was originally.

You can use [`sqlcmd`](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/) mode for this (enable this on the "Query" menu in Management Studio).

```
:setvar dbname "MyNewDatabaseName" 

IF DB_ID('$(dbname)') IS NULL
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(1000);
    SET @SqlQuery = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME('$(dbname)') + ' 
            COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
    EXEC(@SqlQuery) 

    END

GO

USE $(dbname)

GO
```

Comment: +1 - This is exactly (or, well, very close) to what I was answering. But you are really fast :-)

Comment: Is it possible to change from `sqlcmd` mode back to dynamic SQL in the same query?

Comment: @Rick - Having `sqlcmd` mode enabled doesn't prevent you using any SQL constructs. The client tools do the variable substitution before the command is submitted to SQL Server.

Comment: @Rick, if you're happy with dynamic SQL, why not just do `SET @sql = 'USE ' + @dbname + '; ... other dynamic SQL ...;';`?

Comment: I would be more strict with USE $(dbname) - it substitutes variable directly as text when run with real sqlcmd, thus will through error. Correct way compatible both with `sqlcmd mode` and `sqlcmd.exe` is: USE [$(dbname)]

Comment: Also +1 for IF DB_ID() :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add Martin Smith's answer,

If this is so you can deploy your Table creation or Table modification to multiple database you can separate your Database Creation and Object creation scripts, and then run them in sequence using a bat file using the `input file -i`. This enables you to change databases between scripts from master to the new database.

then your batch file might

```
 sqlcmd -S server\Instance -E -i createdatabase.sql 
 sqlcmd -S server\Instance -E -d MyNewDatabaseName -i CreateTables.sql
```

Typically however I've only needed to do this when I was deploying changes to multiple databases (don't ask why) e.g.

```
 sqlcmd -S server\Instance -E -d OneDatabase -i CreateTables.sql 
 sqlcmd -S server\Instance -E -d AnotherDatabase -i CreateTables.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by means of dynamic sql. use a variable to store dbname and use this variable to build a sql string like

```
SELECT @Sql ='SELECT fields FROM ' + @dbname +'.Table'
```

then use `EXEC()` or `sp_executesql` to execute the sql string.

Comment: ..the changes database only seem to apply to the SQL statement inside the parameter the `exec` /  `sp_executesql` functions, not any following SQL statements